# Elasticsearch-py Bulk Update Script With Query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I'd like to use the bulk update api with a script, but i would like to apply the update via a query- and not an id.

A standard bulk-update payload looks something like this-

```
{
  "_index": "users",
  "_type": "user",
  "_op_type": "update",
  "_id": "123",
  "script": { ... }
}
```

But i'd like to instead replace the `_id` property with a query-

```
{
  "_index": "users",
  "_type": "user",
  "_op_type": "update",
  "_query": {"query": {"range": {"age": {"gte": 30}}}},
  "script": { ... }
}
```

Is this possible with the bulk update api? Do I need to run this as a standard update via script api request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with bulk API. What I think you really need is [update_by_query](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.update_by_query) method. For more details, check examples in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html).